# Im looking for a better way to scrape content from a url with curl

Tags: php, parsing, curl, screen-scraping

Im looking for a better way to scrape content from a url with curl, i hope you have idea about multithreads or other ideas. i like to save the html code from over 5.000.000 sites

```html
function curl_download($Url){
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.url.de/?aktion=suche");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

$i = "1";


while ($i <= 450000)
{
    $html = curl_download('http://www.url.de/id='.$i.'&land=be');
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO hb (content)
    VALUES('$html')");
    echo "$i ";
    $i++;
}
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

I'm using multithread curl for check many proxies very fast

That is my code prepared for Your needs

```
$mc = curl_multi_init();
$i=1;
while ($i <= 450000) {
    $thread_no = $i;
    $c [$thread_no] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c [$thread_no], CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.url.de/id='.$i.'&land=be');
    curl_setopt($c [$thread_no], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($c [$thread_no], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c [$thread_no], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($c [$thread_no], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mc, $c [$thread_no]);
    $i++;
}

do {
    while (($execrun = curl_multi_exec($mc, $running)) == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM) ;
    if ($execrun != CURLM_OK) break;
    while ($done = curl_multi_info_read($mc)) {
        $html=curl_multi_getcontent($done['handle']);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO hb (content) VALUES('$html')");
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mc, $done ['handle']);
    }
} while ($running);
curl_multi_close($mc);
```

My direct code with proxies is:

```
$proxies = $proxyL;
$mc = curl_multi_init();
for ($thread_no = 0; $thread_no < count($proxies); $thread_no++) {
    $c [$thread_no] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c [$thread_no], CURLOPT_URL, SERVER_URL . '/checkProxy.php');
    curl_setopt($c [$thread_no], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($c [$thread_no], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c [$thread_no], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($c [$thread_no], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($c [$thread_no], CURLOPT_PROXY, trim($proxies [$thread_no]));
    curl_setopt($c [$thread_no], CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 0);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mc, $c [$thread_no]);
}

do {
    while (($execrun = curl_multi_exec($mc, $running)) == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM) ;
    if ($execrun != CURLM_OK) break;
    while ($done = curl_multi_info_read($mc)) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($done ['handle']);
        if (curl_multi_getcontent($done['handle']) == 'ok') {
            $proxy[] = $proxies [array_search($done['handle'], $c)];
        }
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mc, $done ['handle']);
    }
} while ($running);
curl_multi_close($mc);
```

Comment: the multi API is not **multi-threaded**, it does multiple transfers in the same thread.

Comment: thats true whenn i change $i in 45000 and <=45000 to 1000000 then i have a computer crash, daniel do you have a better idea?

Comment: @Gimo probably You reach limit of output concurrent connections at the time, in my opionion You should make another loop e.g. 50000 in each and run script from cmd.

Comment: @DanielStenberg absolutely You're right, I wrote it in bad words.

Comment: @diaraf when i try over 10000 in one time i get just empty fields in my mysql db

Comment: @Gimo try to echo $html and than die; and look if html was get from url

Comment: it works the problem are the many questions, with my code in my question filled the database complete but very slow. 721 seconds for 500 entrys

Comment: @diaraf i test it now on my server, with my code i get 1000 entries in 39 seconds

Comment: @Gimo maybe target server have some procetion against request per second so that is the reason, I'm using it to check proxy and about 20000 are checked in few seconds.

Comment: @diaraf do you have an example with included proxy server, its not a problem i can use a service for this.